# How to make `-eq` case sensitive in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, comparison-operators

Powershell's `about_Comparison_Operators` page in its ["Common features"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#common-features) section starts with:

> *By default*, string comparisons are case-insensitive.

How do I change that default?

Comment: Use `-ceq`. Mostly all operators have a case sensitive brother. It also has the `-ieq` to make it case insensitive even though it already is. It's just to show the authors intent.

Comment: I know about `c` and `i` prefixes for comparison operators. The documentation implies that it is possible that `-eq` would do case sensitive comparison. I want to know conditions for that. Mostly to have an idea about how fragile the scripts are that use `-eq` for case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: Oof, I gotcha now. I'm not so sure, think I got a lead but, I'm doing laundry rn. Lemme dig into it

Comment: The wording in the docs may be ambiguous, but indeed (and sensibly) the only way to make equality comparisons case-sensitive is to use the `c`-prefixed _variant_ of the `-eq` operator, i.e., `-ceq`. If you think others may be tripped up by the wording, I encourage you to open an issue at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/new/choose

Comment: PowerShell in general is a case-insensitive language, the likable answer is that you can't make pwsh case sensitive-sensitve or string comparison in general case-sensitive unless you want to target .NET APIs such as `String.Equals`

Comment: OK, I might be misinterpreting that sentence. "By default" there probably refers unprefixed comparison operator variants rather than some Powershell setting. Still some clarity is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell language specification 3.0 [section 7.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-07?view=powershell-7.2#78-comparison-operators) states:

> Some comparison-operators (written here as -op) have two variants, one that is case sensitive (-cop), and one that is not (-iop). The -op version is equivalent to -iop. Case sensitivity is meaningful only with comparisons of values of type string. In non-string comparison contexts, the two variants behave the same.

So, as I suspected in my comment, "By default" in the documentation most likely refers to non-prefixed operator variants rather than some Powershell setting.

I.e. there is no way to make `-eq` to be case-sensitive.

The documentation referenced in the question since have been reworded to remove the confusing language, supporting this understanding.

Answer (score -1):

```
$test  = 'Yes'
if($test -eq 'yes') print 'not case sensitive';
```

This code prints 'not case sensitive' in Powershell 5.0

Comment: How does that answer the question?